# Russian babel and chemformula

Tags: babel, chemistry, russian

I want to write chemical formulae in a predominant german Text with a small number of russian words. For that I use `babel` and `chemformula`, but they produce a heavy conflict. My MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\begin{document}
Deutscher Text
\selectlanguage{russian}{русский текст}
\ch{H2O}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error message:

> [path]/chemformula.sty.1168:"xparse/command-already-defined"! See the
>   LaTeX3 documentation for further information. { \chemformula_ch:nn {
>   #1 } { #2 } }

Lines 1167-8 of chemformula.sty contain the following:

```
\NewDocumentCommand \ch { O{}m }
  { \chemformula_ch:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
```

Is there any way to combine these packages?

Comment: Commenting the `chemformula` package and using `\ch` shows a “ch” (I don't know if that have a meaning in a different language). So, if you don't need that, just adding `\let\ch\relax` before loading `chemformula` should be enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Russian module for `babel` defines `\ch` for the “hyperbolic cosine” operator.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,ngerman]{babel}

%%% save the command for the hyperbolic cosine
\let\Ch\ch
%%% undefine \ch
\let\ch\relax
%%%

\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

Deutscher Text

\selectlanguage{russian}{русский текст}
\ch{H2O}

\end{document}
```

If you need “ch” for the hyperbolic cosine, type `\Ch`

[image]